Embedding. Bessel potencial space. Regularity.
For any $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the equation
\begin{align}
(I-\Delta)^{s/2}(u)=f
\end{align}
has a unique solution in the fractional Bessel potential space $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\text{ tempered distribution }\colon \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2))^{s/2}\widehat{u}\right)\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$.
If $s>k+n/p$, then $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset \mathscr{C}
^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ right? where $\mathscr{C}
^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Zygmund space.
This means that, with $s=2$, the equation $(I-\Delta)u=f$ has not solution of clas $\mathscr{C}^2$ because $2>2+n/p$ implies that $0>n/p$. Is it true?
